# Dynamically read changing filename key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-sagemaker

I have `parquet` files that are generated via `spark` and the filename (key) in `s3` will always change post ETL job.  This is the code I use to read the `parquet` files via `boto3` in `sagemaker`.  Looking for a way to dynamically read the `S3` filename (key) since hard-coding the key will fail the read since it changes every time.  How can this be achieved?  Thanks.

```py
filename = "datasets/randomnumbergenerator.parquet"
bucketName = "bucket-name"

buffer = io.BytesIO()
client = boto3.resource("s3")
obj = client.Object(bucketName, filename)
obj.download_fileobj(buffer)
df = pd.read_parquet(buffer)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is working for me.

```py
import boto3
import pandas as pd
import io
import pyarrow
import fastparquet

def dynamically_read_filename_key(bucket, prefix='', suffix=''):
    s3 = boto3\
    .client("s3",\
            region_name=os.environ['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'],\
            aws_access_key_id=os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],\
            aws_secret_access_key=os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'])
    kwargs = {'Bucket': bucket}
    if isinstance(prefix, str):
        kwargs['Prefix'] = prefix
    resp = s3\
    .list_objects_v2(**kwargs)
    for obj in resp['Contents']:
        key = obj['Key']
    if key.startswith(prefix) and key.endswith(suffix):
        return key

filename = "".join(i for i in dynamically_read_filename_key\
                   (bucket="my-bucket",\
                    prefix="datasets/",\
                    suffix=".parquet"))

bucket = "my-bucket"

def parquet_read_filename_key(bucket, filename):
    client = boto3\
    .resource("s3",\
            region_name=os.environ['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'],\
            aws_access_key_id=os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],\
            aws_secret_access_key=os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'])
    buffer = io.BytesIO()
    obj = client.Object(bucket, filename)
    obj.download_fileobj(buffer)
    df = pd.read_parquet(buffer)
    return df

df = parquet_read_filename_key(bucket, filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import fnmatch

filename = "datasets/randomnumbergenerator.parquet"
bucketName = "bucket-name"

buffer = io.BytesIO()
client = boto3.resource("s3")
bucket = client.Bucket(bucketName)
for bucket_object in bucket.objects.all():
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(bucket_object.key, 'datasets/*.parquet'):
        print(bucket_object.key)
```

You'll want to get the list of objects from the bucket, you can then go through the objects to find the one you're looking for.

Update:
You can use fnmatch within the loop to limit to whatever it is you know about the file (assumption with current code is it's in a folder named "datasets" and is of type parquet). This will return all objects in the bucket that match that.

Comment: this prints every prefix within a bucket resulting in many objects ... it does not solve the ability to dynamically read a changing key

Comment: Presumably you would know something about the key and looking at the objects in the bucket you'd be able to limit. The print was just as an example showing that it's going to give you all of the objects in the bucket. If you know absolutely nothing about the final object, I'm not sure how you'd ever know what object you're looking for.